# Android ListView Sections Turning Black

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView with sections and entry items. For example..

```
  Supplies  (Section Item)
     Pens     (Entry Item)
     Pencils
  Groceries
     Eggs
     Lettuce
  Etc....
```

In my list adapter I set the background of the section items to various colors by doing so.

```
  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

This all works fine until I begin to scroll, then the section items turn black (The entry items do not do this). Any one know how to prevent this?

Code for getView() method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    final ItemEchelon i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        if(i.isSection()){
            SectionItemEchelon si = (SectionItem)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_section, null);

            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);

            final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Name);
            sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            if(count == 0)
            {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            if(count == 1)
            {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            if(count == 2)
            {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if(count == 3)
            {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            count ++;
        }else{
            EntryItemEchelon ei = (EntryItemEchelon)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_entry, null);
            final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_entryTitle);
            final TextView score = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_entryScore);

            if (title != null) 
                title.setText(ei.Name);
            if(score != null)
                score.setText(ei.Score);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Fixed problem by removing if statement for changing background color. Made it so you have to initialize a color when constructing a SectionItem.

Answer (score 1):

use this `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` in your `List View`

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your Listview

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Than all will be perfect :).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Variable "count" is your issue?  Looks like you're incrementing it, and when scrolling, you're ignoring the convertView so always creating a new view.  If count >= 4, you get no background...

You *should* use convertView for efficiency, and to help solve this issue.

```
if (convertView != null)
 v = convertView;
else
{
 v = vi.inflate();
 ...
}
```

another big danger, if I'm reading your code correctly, is that you're relying on getView being called in a particular order, section 1 before section 2.  I wouldn't do that...use the int position parameter to determine the section.